# Opencv face recognition using fisherfaces

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition, unhandled-exception

I am working on a face recognition based project and I have used Open cv fisherfaces. I first intend to save the faces of persons in a directory and read from this directory to train the fisher face object but on training Windows shows error. I m using Qt for GUI creation :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name:   QtTracker3.exe
  Application Version:    0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:  5100b46b
  Fault Module Name:  libopencv_core242.dll
  Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 50da6896
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset:   000a38f0
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.3.0.256.1
  Locale ID:  1033
  Additional Information 1:   0a9e
  Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3:   0a9e
  Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

The code strip showing error:

```
void Dialog::on_btnAdd_2_clicked()
{
    tmrTimer->stop();
    ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText("Training Started....!!");

    cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> model = cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer();

    dir=QDir(directory);
    QFileInfoList files;
    QFileInfo file;
    QString filen;


    dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    files=dir.entryInfoList();
    int nofiles;
    nofiles=files.size();
    for(int i=0;i<nofiles;i++)
    {
        file=files.at(i);
        filen=file.absoluteFilePath();
        char* path;
        std::string fname = filen.toStdString();
        path = new char [fname.size()+1];
        strcpy( path, fname.c_str() );

        ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText(path);
        newImages.push_back(cv::imread(path,0)); //std::vector<cv::Mat> newImages; std::vector<int> newLabels; defined in the header
        newLabels.push_back(i);
    }

    model->train(newImages,newLabels);  //this wen commented relieves the error but needs it....
    strcat(home,"\\data.xml");


    model->save(home);


    ui->boxConsole->appendPlainText("Training Completed!!");
    tmrTimer->start();
}
```

Comment: Use debugger to catch error and show us stacktrace if you won't be able to resolve issue by yourself

Comment: i m using qt creator with opencv libraries....can't find any valid debugger in it...

Comment: Qt creator should have "Debug" action somwhere in menu where "Run" action is

Comment: I tried installing cdb (windows debugger tools)...Finally tried debugging but it says                                        Debugging starts
Debugging has failed
Debugging has finished

Comment: You're displaying them as QString, but passing as std::string - codepage conversion happens there. try moving images etc to simple path like "C:\images\" and then try again.

Comment: i found that if i jst comment the model->train() statement it is working but cannot recognize any faces as the model is not trained...also i verified the image paths to be valid by displaying them in the text box of the gui...

Comment: I tried moving to C:\images\...but stil the problem persists...

Comment: I jst mimiced the code here : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html. Instead of reading from the csv file i jst did it using qt directory commands